# Discord chatting Selenium inconsistency

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, discord

I am automating sending a message to a pre determined discord channel in a predetermined server with selenium.

I navigate to the server successfully but there is an inconsistency while locating the text-channel.
When I tried to locate a specific channel on my server it locates it without any issues but when I do it on other server it fails to locate it.

I use the following command to locate channels:

```
channel_element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='channels-5']")
```

I get the specific `id` from the discord website when using `Inspect` in Chrome.

```
setup=[{"server":"RL Insider","channel":"channels-23"}, {"server": "Carrot automation server", "channel": "channels-5"}]

import selenium
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager


driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver.get("https://discord.com/channels/@me")

# login

print(driver.title)
input("input anything when logged in")

def go_to_channel(server, channel_id,message):
    server_element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@aria-label='"+server+"']")
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", server_element)
    input("prompt")
    print(driver.current_url)
    try:
        channel_element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='"+channel_id+"']") #this does not work when used on the RL Insider server
        driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", channel_element)
        input("prompt")
        text_element = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="app-mount"]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/main/form/div/div/div/div/div[3]/div[2]')
        text_element.click()
        text_element.clear()
        for c in message[::-1]:
            text_element.send_keys(c)
        text_element.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
        input("prompt")
    except selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException:
        print("not found by id xpath")

for i in setup:
    go_to_channel(i["server"],i["channel"],string)

driver.close()
```

So I would expect both servers to behave the same because I just can't locate the problematic one.

[image: this is the one that works]

Comment: Why you are navigating? You can just use URL of the channel

Comment: @KhanSaad that is what I ended up doing

Answer (score 0):

There can be inconsistencies with the speed of processing of your code. The server may have more computing power and runs the codes faster. In this way, the elements you are trying to find might not have loaded yet. I would suggest to use waiting for element before finding it.

Here are some examples :

https://seleniumbyexamples.github.io/wait

Comment: Please add details from the link to the answer.  Links can be broken in future which will invalidate the answer.

Comment: Added the links. Thank you